# update specific line with value using Python

Tags: python

```
tstep1= 8
tstep2=10
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 587:
            f.write(str(tstep1))
        elif i==607:
            f.write(str(tstep2))
        f.write(line)
```

When I run this script, it doesnt update the line, it add the number to the previous one, 
For example instead of changing 9 with 8, it will add 8 next to 9 so it will look like 89
How can I fix it?
Best Regards

Comment: Why are you opening the .txt file twice on of interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
f.write(line)
```

to

```
else:
    f.write(line)
```

Comment: Would you please do me one more favour, how can I paste the value with (*31)? So it appears 8*31 and 10*31? Best Regards

Comment: f.write(line + "*31")